# source code for eclipse plugin dependencies

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I am trying to learn about eclipse plugin development.I downloaded ***Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers*** in **Helios** distribution. I am able to create plugin development project using plugin development wizard[image: see attached image]. Now the problem is am not able to view the source code of eclipse plugin dependencies.I searched the internet for source attachments, but didn't find it.Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *just* want to play around with plug-in development, then you really don't need to integrate the different IDE capabilities, and can probably live with separate Eclipse installations and workspaces.

Actually, the more capabilities/Eclipse editions, you try to integrate, the more limits you set up for other plug-ins/features/capabilities. At some point, it can get impossible to integrate 3rd party capabilities such as those from TaskTop and Atlassian...

If you don't need the Java EE capabilities, consider using either the classic 
Eclipse edition or the RCP edition.

Comment: Thanks for answering.. I am developing plugin which I use in web development. So if I am able to develop it in J2EE edition, then I can test it with out installing.

Comment: Well, you do have to install it in the current Eclipse installation. Something that can be done directly from the "Export Plug-in" wizard, but it is not recommended. If at all possible, create and use a feature and update site for the new plug-in. This will also allow you to distribute and update the plug-in as you add functionality and/or fix problems... Also, it is considered good latin to keep the PDE IDE separate from the target platform to help avoid the case where your plug-in prevents the target platform to start - if the two are identical, you can be in very deep problems :-)

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse plugin development download Eclipse Classic distribution which includes SDK from [here](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/).

Eclipse IDE for Java EE description:

> Tools for Java developers creating Java EE and Web applications, including a Java IDE, tools for Java EE, JPA, JSF, Mylyn and others.

Eclipse Classic description:

> The classic Eclipse download: the Eclipse Platform, Java Development Tools, and Plug-in Development Environment, including source and both user and programmer documentation.

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question. But I actually wanted to do plugin development in J2EE eclipse edition. I am trying to develop a plugin which I use for web development. So if I am able to develop plugin in J2EE eclipse edition, then I can test it with out installing it.

Answer (score -1):

Also, if you want to see the sourcecode of any plugin dependency, you can check it out from CVS at :pserver:anonymous@dev.eclipse.org:/cvsroot/eclipse

Be careful to get the right version, though.

Cheers,
 Rob

Comment: Not a good idea... Just update your installation with the PDE tools and all source features. The later are needed when you want to add extension points.

Comment: But there are plugin sources you won't get with that - or am I mistaken?

Comment: Well, there are a few plug-ins where you don't get sources or the `.exsd` files - but none of these are of any relevance for your ordinary plug-in development... It can be rather difficult to get the correct sources for your platform - you need to specify the correct version numbers for everything, as you otherwise will be more confused than helped by the sources :-)

Comment: Could be the reason I feel confused about some aspects there.. ;-)
Thanks for clarification.